# How to pass parameters to Airflow on_success_callback and on_failure_callback

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have implemented email alerts on success and failure using on_success_callback and on_failure_callback.

According to [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator),

> a context dictionary is passed as a single parameter to this function.

How can I pass another parameter to these callback methods?

Here is my code

```
from airflow.utils.email import send_email_smtp

def task_success_alert(context):
    subject = "[Airflow] DAG {0} - Task {1}: Success".format(
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[0], 
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[1]
        )
    html_content = """
    DAG: {0}<br>
    Task: {1}<br>
    Succeeded on: {2}
    """.format(
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[0], 
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[1], 
        datetime.now()
        )
    send_email_smtp(dag_vars["dev_mailing_list"], subject, html_content)

def task_failure_alert(context):
    subject = "[Airflow] DAG {0} - Task {1}: Failed".format(
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[0], 
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[1]
        )
    html_content = """
    DAG: {0}<br>
    Task: {1}<br>
    Failed on: {2}
    """.format(
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[0], 
        context['task_instance_key_str'].split('__')[1], 
        datetime.now()
        )
    send_email_smtp(dag_vars["dev_mailing_list"], subject, html_content)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 13),
    'on_success_callback': task_success_alert,
    'on_failure_callback': task_failure_alert
}
```

I intend to move the callbacks to another package and pass the email address as parameter.

Comment: When I use CONTEXT it my tasks finishes but dag keeps running.It never ends. any suggestions.  I am using  def task_alert(context):  
    dag_id = context['dag'].dag_id    \n
    task_id = context['task_instance']. task_id     I am calling on_failure_callback=task_alert

Comment: Use the xcom_push and xcom_pull

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could define a function inside your dag that calls the function from your package. And while calling that function, pass email as an argument. You can refine it further at your DAG level to pass only information required for the emails.

```
from package import outer_task_success_callback
email = 'xyz@example.com'

def task_success_alert(context):
    dag_id = context['dag'].dag_id
    task_id = context['task_instance']. task_id
    outer_task_success_callback(dag_id, task_id, email)
    
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 13),
    'on_success_callback': task_success_alert,
    'on_failure_callback': task_failure_alert
}
```

This will allow you to customize before you call the function in your package.

On a side note, airflow has smtp email functionality. Instead of writing your own solution, you can utilize those.

Comment: When I use CONTEXT it my tasks finishes but dag keeps running.It never ends. any suggestions.

Comment: Can't understand or debug without a code example. Add a question and tag it airflow. I will check and answer if I am able to

Comment: def notify_email(context):
    import inspect
   
    """Send custom email alerts."""
    import smtplib, ssl
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    sender_email = 'abc@gmail.com'
    receiver_email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    password = "abc"
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
       
    #task_instance = context['task'].task_id
    dag_instance=context['dag_id'].dag_id        When using context['dag_id'].dag_id my dag keeps on running task finishes and mail is not sent

Comment: @Gabriel Eckers The SMTP util in airflow still provides an option to send emails as a Task. While on_success option is not available, email functionality can be kept within airflow DAG.

Answer (score 7):

You can use partial to create a function with a predefined argument like:

```
from functools import partial
new_task_success_alert = partial(task_success_alert, email='your_email')
```

And then add the new function as a callback:

```
on_success_callback=new_task_success_alert
```

Comment: This answer is much better than the highlighted response because the former relies on knowing the file name at the time of import.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a task that its only purpose is to push configuration setting through `xcoms`. You can pull the configuration via `context` as the `task_instance` object is included in `context`.

```
def push_configuration(ti, params):
    ti.xcom_push(key='conn_id', value=params)

def task_success_alert(context):
    ti = context.get('ti') 
    params = ti.xcom_pull(key='params', task_ids='Settings')
    ...


step0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Settings',
        python_callable=push_configuration,
        op_kwargs={'params': params})

step1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='step1',
        bash_command='pwd',
        on_success_callback=task_success_alert)
```