# In Airflow how can I pass parameters using context to on_success_callback function handler?

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow how can I pass parameters using context to on_success_callback function handler?

This is my test code:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import MSTeamsWebhookOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime
from transaction_analytics import helpers
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain

# Parameters & variables
schedule_interval        = "0 20 * * *"

def _task_success_callback(context):
    dagid         = context["task_instance"].dag_id
    duration      = context["task_instance"].duration
    executiondate = context["execution_date"]
    logurl        = context["task_instance"].log_url.replace("localhost", "agbqhsbldd017v.agb.rbxd.ds")# workaround until we config airflow
    pp1           = context["params"].param1 
    #pp1          = "{{ params.param1 }}"
    ms_teams_op = MSTeamsWebhookOperator(
        task_id="success_notification",
        http_conn_id="msteams_airflow",
        message="DAG {ppram1} `{dag}`  finished successfully!".format(dag=context["task_instance"].dag_id, ppram1=pp1),
        subtitle="Execution Date = {p1}, Duration = {p2}".format(p1=executiondate,p2=duration),
        button_text = "View log",
        button_url = "{log}".format(log=logurl),
        theme_color="00FF00"#,
        #proxy= "http://10.72.128.202:3128"
    )
    ms_teams_op.execute(context)

    main_dag = DAG('test_foley',
            schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
            description='Test foley',
            start_date=datetime(2020, 4, 19),
            default_args=None,
            max_active_runs=2,
            default_view='graph',     # Default view graph
            #orientation='TB', # Top-Bottom graph
            on_success_callback=_task_success_callback,
            #on_failure_callback=outer_task_failure_callback,
            catchup=False, # Do not catchup, run only latest
            params={
              "param1": "value1",
              "param2": "value2"
            }
           )

################################### START ######################################
dag_chain = []

start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', retries = 3, dag=main_dag)
dag_chain.append(start)

step1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='step1',
    bash_command='pwd',
    dag=main_dag,
)
dag_chain.append(step1)

step2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='step2',
    bash_command='exit 0',
    dag=main_dag,
)
dag_chain.append(step2)


end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', dag=main_dag)
dag_chain.append(end)

chain(*dag_chain)
```

I have an event handler function **_task_success_callback** that handles success.
In DAG I have **on_success_callback=_task_success_callback** that captures that event.

And it works... but now I need to pass some parameters into **_task_success_callback**.
What  is the best method?

As that function receives context I tried to create parameters in DAG as you can see:

```
        params={
          "param1": "value1",
          "param2": "value2"
        }
```

But seems I cannot access them?

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong to access params?
2. Is there a better way to pass parameters?

NOTE: I saw this similar question [How to pass parameters to Airflow on_success_callback and on_failure_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697838/how-to-pass-parameters-to-airflow-on-success-callback-and-on-failure-callback) with one answer... and works. But what I am looking is to use context to pass parameters....

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're looking to use the context and your linked answer won't work?

Comment: It is just to have cleaner code. I have many DAGs, each one notifies to Teams with different values for in MsTeamsWebHook operator. With current solution I have to ling DAG to 2 functions (success and failure) and those functions to the common function in library. I have 32 DAGs that means creating also 64 functions (2 per DAG) with the only difference of parameters (http_conn_id, message, title).
If I am able to pass parameters via context I would have 32 DAGs that call directly common function with parameters, saving me from having those ugly 64 functions...

Comment: Does it have to be `context["params"]['param1']` instead of `context["params"].param1`?

Answer (score 5):

Recall that Airflow process files are simply Python, and provided you don't introduce too much overhead during their parsing (*since Airflow parses the files frequently, and that overhead can add up*), you can use everything Python can do. In particular for your case I recommend returning a nested function (*closure*) for your callback:

Put this in a file adjacent your Airflow processes, let's say `on_callbacks.py`

```py
def success_ms_teams(param_1, param_2):

    def callback_func(context):
        print(f"param_1: {param_1}")
        print(f"param_2: {param_2}")
        # ... trimmed for brevity ...#
        ms_teams_op.execute(context)

    return callback_func
```

Then in your processes you can do this:

```py
from airflow import models

from on_callbacks import success_ms_teams

with models.DAG(
    ...
    on_success_callback=success_ms_teams(
        "value1", # These values become the
        "value2", # `param_1` and `param_2` 
    )
) as dag:
    ...
```

Comment: this produces the following error  ` python_callable param must be callable`

Comment: The value you've passed to `python_callable` isn't callable.  Try opening a question with your code and logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a task that its only purpose is to push configuration setting through `xcoms`. You can pull the configuration via `context` as the `task_instance` object is included in `context`.

```
def push_configuration(ti, params):
    ti.xcom_push(key='conn_id', value=params)

def _task_success_callback(context):
    ti = context.get('ti') 
    params = ti.xcom_pull(key='params', task_ids='Settings')
    ...


step0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Settings',
        python_callable=push_configuration,
        op_kwargs={'params': params})

step1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='step1',
        bash_command='pwd',
        on_success_callback=_task_success_callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used partials to call a fallback function with different connections:

```
from functools import *

# pass extra params here
def my_conn_callback(context, slack_conn_id, slack_channel):
  print(context)
  print(slack_conn_id)
  print(slack_channel)

# this is for the on_failure_callback
task_fail_slack_alert_callback_my_conn = partial(my_conn_callback, 
slack_conn_id = "slack-conn", slack_channel = "#slack_channel")

# this is how airflow calls it internally:
print(task_fail_slack_alert_callback_my_conn('context'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass user-defined parameters in the definition of DAG in case of either on_success_callback or on_failure_callback like this
`params={'custom_param': 'custom_param_value'}` along with on_success_callback or on_success_callback function call. It adds values in form of key-value pair as a dictionary inside `context['params']`

You can access the value of your customized parameter anywhere inside a function call like this
`context['params'].get('custom_param')`

```py
def dag_failure_notification_alert(context):
    print(context['params'].get('custom_param'))

default_args = {
    "owner": "abcd",
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 12, 12),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(),
    "schedule_interval": "@daily"
}

dag = DAG('alert_notification_dummy_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          catchup=False,
          on_failure_callback=dag_failure_notification_alert,
          params={
              'custom_param': 'custom_param_value'
          }
          )
```

Here you can pass any number of parameters like

```
params={"x": Param(5, type="integer", minimum=3)},
```

or

```
params={'x': [10,20,30]}
```

for reference, kindly look at [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/params.html)